# How do I terminate an input by ending the file in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, eof

The code I am working on is a simple subtraction work but my problem arises when I need to end the inputs.

The problem tells me that the input is terminated by end of file and I have no idea what that means when the question has any number of inputs.

```
while(True):
    data=[]
    data= list(map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split()))
    if (data[1]>data[0]):
        total=data[1]-data[0]
    else:
        total=data[0]-data[1]
    print(total)
```

How do I change this code to allow it to end without the user inputting anything

Comment: Read about loops here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: Your input is currently `stdin` rather than a file. It would terminate on End of File if you were reading a file. You have two options, change your condition in the `while` loop to be something other than True, or change your data to read from a file instead of `stdin`.

Comment: [End Of File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) is a special "letter" that signifies the end of the file. Python can handle it automatically. If you replace the `while True:` with `for line in sys.stdin:` then you'll have a for loop where `line` will be a variable containing each line of the input.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983475/reading-stdin-line-at-a-time-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in comments, use loop over `sys.stdin`. I've also added some other improvements:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    data = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
    total = abs(data[1] - data[0])
    print(total)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help it worked for my problem

Answer (score 2):

I came across this answer while researching the problem on the Open Kattis platform:

https://open.kattis.com/problems/different

I think we are both working on the same.  But the above solution did not work, I kept getting a "Run Time Error" It's hard to figure out what the error is when you work with Python on Kattis as they almost never give you any sort of stack trace type output.

I needed to add an import for sys.  I figured this out because my IDE indicated it was needed.

```
import sys

for i in sys.stdin:
    a, b = [int(x) for x in i.split()]
    print(abs(a - b))
```